# Is it possible to add mingw gcc tool chain to Visual Studio ?

Tags: visual-studio, mingw

Is it possible to have multiple tool chains in Visual Studio(2010, 2012) ?
Can someone do me a favor and tell if if its possible and how we can achieve such a thing?

Comment: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/mingw/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force visual studio to use mingw compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174607/can-i-force-visual-studio-to-use-mingw-compiler)

Comment: Any opensource counterpart, or a way that i can do it myself is greatly appreciated.